# Extract json values as array with jq in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

How to extract json's values as JSON array with `jq`?

For example for the below json:

```
{
   "a" : 1,
   "b" : 2
}
```

I would like to extract values as JSON array:

`[
1,
2
]`

How to do it with `jq`?
I found a way to extract keys only in the [docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#TypesandValues):

`echo $json | jq keys` returns:

```
[
"a",
"b"
]
```

Comment: The keys `a`, `b`, need to be double quoted for `jq` to parse it as a valid JSON

Comment: Do you mean as a JSON array, or as a Bash array, or just the values, one per line?

Comment: @tripleee json array, similar to `keys` filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use `to_entries` then `map` to extract only the values:

```
$ echo '{
   "a" : 1,
   "b" : 2
}' | jq 'to_entries|map(.value)'
[
  1,
  2
]
```

Another solution, simpler and faster, is to use just `map(.)`:

```
$ echo '{
   "a" : 1,
   "b" : 2
}' | jq 'map(.)'
[
  1,
  2
]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
echo $json | jq '[.[]]'
```

output:

```
[
  1,
  2
]
```